# SQL Server 2012 SqlCLR reads configurations from machine.config instead of sqlservr.exe.config

Tags: c#, configuration, sql-server-2012, clr, sqlclr

I have a SQLCLR project deployed to SQL Server 2012, the project reads some app settings from the configuration file, the configuration file for sql must be inside the `\Binn` folder of the sql root folder, but it fails to read the settings from there and instead reads the configurations from the machine.config file, and when I tried to add the system.configuration to the sql assemblies I am getting the below error:

> The assembly name 'System.Configuration' being registered has an
>   illegal name that duplicates the name of a system assembly

Is there anything that I am missing there?

Aran

Answer (score 0):

Ok - as a solution you can connect to the same database as the one that your function is deployed to, using the following code I connect to the database and read the settings that I want from the database.

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(**"context connection = true"**))
        {            
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Value FROM GlobalConfigSettings WHERE ID = " + ConstFynixConnectionStringId, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                fynixConnString = dr["Value"].ToString();
            }
            conn.Close();                  
        }
```